# Simple linear linked list in VB.NET using class

Tags: vb.net, singly-linked-list

How can a linear linked list be implemented in VB.NET using class?

How can this class be modified for linear linked list?

Also the methods for traversing the list, deleting nodes, etc.

```
Public Class clsHol
    Private dt As Date
    Private tp As String
    Private remark As String

    Public Function setValues(ByVal d As Date, ByVal t As String, ByVal r As String)
        remark = r
        tp = t
        remark = r
    End Function

    Public Function getDate()
        Return dt
    End Function

    Public Function getTyp()
        Return tp
    End Function

    Public Function getRemark()
        Return remark
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: As long as you haven't yet figured out how to use the Property keyword, do use the built-in .NET LinkedList class instead.  It will keep you out of trouble and supports all the operations you require.  This otherwise reads like a homework assignment, one you are no doubt expected to complete yourself.

Comment: where to find that built in .NET linked List class?? actually i thought of using a liked list for undo redo buttons.. am working on my project college attendance system, and i need to work on databases.. so i thought of using a liked list to save the records temporarily and add-remove nodes as per undo redo operations..

Comment: Here is the LinkedList class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: For undo and redo you need stacks, not linked lists. `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<T>`.

Comment: not linked list? what if the user edits some record which is not at the top of stack. because the data table will be shown in a data grid view. so he is permitted to update also. in that case i don't think stack will work. ok it will be good because we will only have to push or pop. ok thanks.. thank you all.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim voLList As New LinkedList(Of clsHol)

    voLList.AddFirst(new clsHol())
    voLList.AddLast(new clsHol())
    voLList.AddLast(new clsHol())
End Sub
```

Comment: There is an edit suggested with the words "I am retarded". The suggested edit should be rejected.